# How to scale text in figures with preserving the aspect ratio in Latex?

Tags: text, latex, scaling, figure

I have a problem whith figures in latex: When I insert a figure I have the problem of text scaling without preserving the aspect ratio. The text size in each figure is different from the other figures due to its different scale. Could you please tell me how can I solve this issue?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things that contain text are best not included as images to avoid this problem. Instead one could

1. create the graphic with latex, e.g. using Ti*k*Z, pgfplots, the `picture` environment and similar tools
2. if your figure is a vector graphic, you could use `inkscape` to export it to `pdf+tex`. The resulting figure will only have the graphical elements, while all text elements will be included in a separate file using the latex `picture` environment. This will ensure that the text size will be the same as the surrounding text

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my issue.